# Insert data into .mdb file through node in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ms-access, amazon-ec2

I've found several ways of reading data and also with `node-adodb` I can insert data too into .mdb file through node but in Windows.

However our project is being deployed in Amazon EC2 linux instance so I was looking for a way to execute that `insert` query (which works in Windows) into my .mdb file, but I couldn't find one.

I know .mdb databases are not popular, but It's mandatary since It's a legacy feature we cannot get rid of.

EDIT 1: The problem is that `node-adodb` (the module that worked for inserting data) uses Windows drivers to create the connection, so It doesn't work in Linux (for example, this script which is used under the hood assumes having .exe and windows file system https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb/blob/master/lib/proxy.js also when creating a new connection you do `const connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=data-rellenar.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;');`
). 
So what I need is an alternative, since the project will be deployed on Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: The problem is that `node-adodb` (the module that worked for inserting data) uses Windows drivers to create the connection, so It doesn't work in Linux (for example, this script which is used under the hood assumes having .exe and windows file system https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb/blob/master/lib/proxy.js). So what I need is an alternative, since the project will be deployed on Linux.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc